# Merge 2 tables into 1. Add values next to each other, vba or formula

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for a way to merge 2 tables together but the volumes are in different columns.

For some reason you cant add image to posts, never mind.

Say Col A has Product, Col B has Place, Col C has Sales and Col D has Units.

Table 1 has Col A,B and C (Column D = Blank)
Table 2 has Colum C = blank

Basically, both tables have the same structure but one has units populated and sales are blank, whereas the second one has sales populated and units blank...

Now I want to create 1 table that combines this. So 1 table and it has sales and units next to each other...

The final problem, they may not add up line  by line... meaning, I need if the product and place doesn't match in both tables, add to end as single row and (lets say it has units) value will appear in unit column but sales would be blank, and vice versa.

Is this possible? Happy with either a VBA or formulae solution in excel.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a combination of `index(match(` See for example this tutorial: https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/

Comment: Hard to explain without showing. Index(Match will not work as I am merging them into 1 table with no dublicates. Match will only find the first value and give that, where in the original table the UI may be in multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and easy answer, I filtered to get unique combinations only pasted as values and then for Units I did a sumif on the product against one table to get units and then in the cell next to it (sales) I did a sumif against the second table on the product combination.

Though done in VBA

Then ran some code that checked if both units and sales was = 0 (0 in each cell next to another) then removed entirerow. If anyone wants to see the code. Let me know and I'll post.

The first step was to create a UI with all combinations and copy/paste unique values only....

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "UI"
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=RC[1]&"",""&RC[2]&"",""&RC[3] 
&"",""&RC[4]&"",""&RC[5]&"",""&RC[6]&"",""&RC[7]&"",""&RC[8]"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A27912")
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range("A1:A30000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range( 
_
    "O1"), Unique:=True
Range("O1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Select
```

The next thing was to sum products next to the columns and add in the "text to columns" So baically a sumif against the UI for sales and next to it for quantity...

```
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Next").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("A:A").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), 
 Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Sheets("Other").Select
Range("B1:L1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Next").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("L1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.349986266670736
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "UI"
Range("L2").Select
Sheets("Other").Select
Range("O2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Next").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("J2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF('Other'!R2C1:R50000C1,RC12,'Other'!R2C[1]:R50000C[1])"
Range("J2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:K2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("J2:K2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:K10000")

Range("J2:K10000").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("L:L").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

(This section of the code isn't very neat but it does the trick...)

Next I removed the 0s if both values are 0s...

```
Dim VRange As Range

Set VRange = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("J1"), 
ActiveSheet.Range("J1").End(xlDown))

With VRange
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0"
.Resize(.Rows.Count - 
1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
.AutoFilter
 End With

 Sheets("Other").Select
 Range("A1:I1").ClearContents
 Range("A1:I1").Value = Sheets("Data").Range("C1:K1").Value

Dim URange As Range

Set URange = Range(ActiveSheet.Range("J1"), 
ActiveSheet.Range("J1").End(xlDown))

With URange
.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0"
.Resize(.Rows.Count - 
1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
.AutoFilter
End With
```

Please note that I have made some changes to this so refer to your own data and match it...

Hope this is all the code for the right thing :P There is a lot more involved any I may have copied over the wrong code :(

Comment: Please do include code in your answer if it's relevant. That's far more helpful for when people find it via Google later on.

Comment: Unfair to give down vote just because I didn't add the code... still added the solution... Just poor manners.

Comment: There's nothing rude about downvotes. They're a deliberate feature of the site.